# Doubt regarding the square of a no. $<2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

For $x<2$ which of the following statement is ***always*** true:-

1. $x$ is negative
2. $2x \ge x$
3. $x^2 \ge x$
4. None of these

Taking examples:-
$1$ is false, If $x$ is negative $2$ is false 
But $3$ is always true So answer must be $3$
But the answer key says that the answer is $4$.
Who is correct? If I am wong, please explain.

Comment: what's $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$?

Comment: Hi! First off, what is $x$?

Comment: 3 isn't always true. I suggest drawing the graph of $y=x^2-x$ for $x$ between $0$ and $2$.

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe $x$ is a real no.

Comment: Maybe of interest. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481633/how-to-prove-forall-x-x2-gt-x/2481822#2481822

Answer (score 0):

How you said, 1-2 is true. But taking any $x\in (0,1)$ we have $x^2< x$. Therefore the correct answer is 4.